# How do I draw a curved line with rounded corners in Adobe Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, drawing

I tried to draw such a triangle using 3 circles and lines, but I couldn't fill the shape with color. Using a line and giving it a rounding also did not work, using a square with rounded corners - I'm not sure this is the best way. What tools and approach should I use to draw such a shape
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using Illustrator for this? There's a very simple way. Draw a line, with a thick stroke, round caps and round corner joins, expand, then use the corner widget control to round the inner corner only.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of your problem there are two features you need to consider: `Stroke Join` or/and `Object > Corner Options...`:

[image]